# Merging Date and Time columns is a particular format

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to make changes to my csv files at once.I used the code below but run into a problem merging the Date and Time column.

This is an example of what i have:

```
Date         Time
11/4/2016  10:30:10
11/4/2016  10:30:10
```

I want a column named `rtime` that has the combined Date and Time in this format below:

This is what I want:

```
 Date         Time          rtime
11/4/2016  10:30:00    2016-11-04 10:30:00
11/4/2016  10:30:10    2016-11-04 10:30:10
```

I used the code below:

```
cities.cleaned <- cities %>%
  rename(pm = `μg/m³`) %>%
  filter( !is.na(pm)) %>%
  mutate(rtime = paste(Date, Time),
        rtime = mdy_hm(rtime))
```

I got this warning message:

> Warning message: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

The renaming and the filtering worked fine, the problem came from the mutate section.

When I viewed it using `view(cities.cleaned)` I saw the rtime column but there nothing in the column, it was all NA.

Comment: Use mdy_hms() rather than mdy_hm()

Comment: Try to look at `lubridate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using mdy_hm() and you have time with format HMS, that's why it fail to parse. Try:

```
df = read.table(text ="Date         Time
11/4/2016  10:30:00
11/4/2016  10:30:10", header = T)
library(lubridate)
df$rtime = mdy_hms(paste(df$Date,df$Time))

       Date     Time               rtime
1 11/4/2016 10:30:10 2016-11-04 10:30:00
2 11/4/2016 10:30:10 2016-11-04 10:30:10
```

Or in base R:

```
df$rtime = strptime(paste(df$Date,df$Time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

PS: 1- Make sure the format of your date is month/day and not day/month. 2- BTW, the that you provide does not produce the desired output.

Comment: Thank you! the issue was using mdy_hms() . I changed it mdy_hms() and it worked fine.